# Playframework get value from form object

Tags: java, forms, validation, playframework-2.1

Hey i've a form with some data. At the top and at the end of the form i've the same input field. It's for a password confirmation. Here you can see how i try to get the value from the field in order to validate if the user entered a value.

```
userForm.field("passwordConfirm").valueOr("").isEmpty()
```

Now to my problem. If i enter the password at the input field at the top i'm able to get the value out of the field, but if i enter the password at the input field at the end of the form i don't get the value. How can i get the value from the second input field instead of the first one?
I used the input helper for password fields from play.

```
@inputPassword(userForm("passwordConfirm"), '_label -> Messages("view.user.passwordConfirmation"), '_showConstraints -> true, 'autocomplete -> "off")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using that exact input helper twice in your HTML template, this will generate two input fields *with the same name*.

When you only fill in the field at the top of the form and submit, the resulting HTTP POST request will look like:

```
...
passwordConfirm=hello
passwordConfirm=
...
```

When you only fill in the field at the bottom of the form and submit, the request will look like:

```
...
passwordConfirm=
passwordConfirm=hello
...
```

I think Play's approach to form binding will pick up the value of the first `passwordConfirm` entry it finds, which explains the behaviour you are seeing.

Your options are to:

1. Name the two password fields differently and then check both fields using the two different names in your validation tier.
2. Keep your HTML the same and loop over the form data manually yourself, instead of asking Play to bind it to one of your POJOs.